# hibernate-envers onetomany join class not audited, but join columns need to be audited

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hibernate-envers

I am trying to save the join columns values in the audit tables while not auditing the join table.

Here are my entity classes.

Audited Class INFO:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "INFO")
public class Info extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    /*More Columns */ 

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "FIRST_NAME", referencedColumnName = "FIRST_NAME"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "LAST_NAME", referencedColumnName = "LAST_NAME") })
    @NotAudited
    private Details details;


}
```

Not Audited Class: Details:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DETAILS")
public class Details extends AbstractEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private DetailsPK detailsPK;
    /*More Columns */ 

}
```

Primary Key/ Join fields are defined here:

```
@Embeddable
public class DetailsPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

}
```

Here, the Details information is static... It does not change... Hence, need ot be audited.... But, when auditing INFO changes, I want the INFO_AUD table to capture both the first name and last name as well... Is there a way to specify this?

Thank you,
Joe.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? I am having the same problem here...

Answer (score 1):

Since the fields you want are part of the primary key, you can very easily do this by specifying a special audit annotation attribute:

```
@ManyToOne
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
private Details details;
```

In short, this instructs Envers that the associated entity `Details` is not an audited entity; however the audit schema should take a snapshot of the associated entity's primary key columns.

So you should expect `Info_AUD` to have two columns that represent the name values called `details_FIRST_NAME` and `details_LAST_NAME`.

You won't need to do anything else special with your data model as Envers will make sure that as you change the `Details` object associated to `Info`, that the name columns are updated in the historical row snapshot accordingly.

Comment: Naros, Thank you for your help... I tried the above solution... But the first_name and last_name in the audit tables are still not populated...

Also, my assumption was that in your code... The details.getId() method is the details.getDetailsPK() method. I added getters and setters to the shadow columns in the INFO entity.

Please advise... Can you also, please elaborate on why we need the resolveAuditedShadowColumns method in the details setter...

I apologize in advance, as I am completely new to envers and trying to understand that...

Comment: @Joe I completly rewrote the answer.  My prior answer was a bit convoluted and after doing some experimentation; I found a better solution that fits very nicely to your needs and avoids any unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I tried doing this before I posted my question and it did not work... I retried just in case... and it is still not working.... The below is the lines of code I tried.

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "FIRST_NAME", referencedColumnName = "FIRST_NAME"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "LAST_NAME", referencedColumnName = "LAST_NAME") })
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    private Details details;


Note: My Info_Aud table has FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME columns but  not details_First_name and details_last_name columsn.

Comment: What version of Hibernate Envers are you using?

Comment: <version>5.2.11.Final</version>